App Script find and replace, multiple occurrences within cells in a specific range
I am trying to search a specific range for a character (", ") and replace all occurrences of that character with a new character ("|").  As an example, the current cells may have "apples, bananas, oranges, nuts" and I would like the cells, after running the script to have "apples|bananas|oranges|nuts".  I need the script to run only in the specified columns.
I am new to scripts and cobbled together some code from different threads which works (partially). The problem is that the code - shown below - only replaces the FIRST instance of the character in a cell. In my example, instead of the product being the desired "apples|bananas|oranges|nuts" - the product is "apples|bananas, oranges, nuts"
I am not sure how to make the code loop back through until all of the ", " in the cells within the specified ranges have been replaced. The code I am using is below:
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("g2:h998");
  var to_replace = ", ";
  var replace_with = "|";
  replaceInSheet(sheet, range, to_replace, replace_with);
}

function replaceInSheet(sheet, range, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //Confirm
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var result = ui.alert(
    "Will update to add " + replace_with + ".",
    'Are you sure you want to continue?',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {

    // User clicked "Yes".
    spread.toast("Will update", "ALERT");

    var data = range.getValues();

    var oldValue = "";
    var newValue = "";
    var cellsChanged = 0;


    for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
      for (var item = 0; item < data[row].length; item++) {
        oldValue = data[row][item];
        newValue = data[row][item].replace(to_replace, replace_with);
        if (oldValue != newValue) {
          cellsChanged++;
          data[row][item] = newValue;
        }
      }
    }

      range.setValues(data);
      spread.toast(cellsChanged + " cells changed", "STATUS");
  }

  else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    spread.toast("No action taken", "ABANDONED");
  }
}


Replace all with text finder.  go to the sheet and select the range and then run the function
function myfunk() {
  const to_replace = ", ";
  const replace_with = "|";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  rg.createTextFinder(to_replace).replaceAllWith(replace_with);
}


Range.textFinder()


I don't want to have to select the range manually - I would like to have it run on open automatically after having specified the range in the script.

HA! But, you did give me the answer!  Changing the replace to replaceAll in this line gave me the result I wanted:  OLD - newValue = data[row][item].replace(to_replace, replace_with);  NEW - newValue = data[row][item].replaceAll(to_replace, replace_with);

just change getActiveRange to getRange and fill in the correct parameters
